# IndexError: list index out of range (Python program to convert an address to geo coordinates

Tags: python, indexoutofrangeexception

I tried the following code to convert the addresses into geo coordinates and i got the below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/sessions/cac34a57fd2090d2/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    my_geo = results[0]['geometry']['location']
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Heres the code which I have written:

```
import requests
geo_url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json'

my_address = {'address': '45 Ramkrishana Road,East Burdwan, West Bengal, India', 
             'language': 'en'}

response = requests.get(geo_url, params = my_address)

results = response.json()['results']

my_geo = results[0]['geometry']['location']

print("Longitude:",my_geo['lng'],"\n","Latitude:",my_geo['lat'])
```

Answer (score 0):

To use the Google maps API, you need an [API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start#get-a-key), which requires that you set up a billing account. Do you have an API key? A possible query string to their API that Google provides as an example looks like this:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

As you can see, the last parameter is your API key, which is required. If you don't pass an API key, the response will look like this:

```
{
   "error_message" : "You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs. For additional information, please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account",
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

`results` will be an empty list, hence the `IndexError`.

Comment: import requests
geo_url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=APIKEY'
my_address = {'address': '1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA',
             'language': 'en'}
response = requests.get(geo_url, params = my_address)
results = response.json()['results']
my_geo = results[0]['geometry']['location']

print("Longitude:",my_geo['lng'],"\n","Latitude:",my_geo['lat'])      I HAVE ADDED MY API KEY BUT STILL FACING THE SAME ERROR